# Select last group of data

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a table like this

**Measurements**

```
id    object_id   generated_at (v)    
110   4           2012-11-13 10:29:00   
109   4           2012-11-13 10:28:00   
108   4           2012-11-13 10:27:00
107   3           2012-11-13 10:26:00
106   3           2012-11-13 10:25:00
105   4           2012-11-13 10:24:00
104   4           2012-11-13 10:23:00
103   1           2012-11-13 10:22:00
102   1           2012-11-13 10:21:00
...
```

ordered by `generated_at` column.

My question: is there any ability to select

```
id    object_id   generated_at (v)    
110   4           2012-11-13 10:29:00   
109   4           2012-11-13 10:28:00   
108   4           2012-11-13 10:27:00
```

last group(ordered by `generated_at`) of measurements with same `object_id` ?

It could be example in rails for Measurement model or just SQL query, thanks for any help!

Comment: `Measurement.order('generated_at ASC').group('object_id').limit(4)` ?
And eventually to filter it with a specific id: `Measurement.order('generated_at ASC').group('object_id').where(object_id: my_obj_id).limit(4)` Please let me know if its what you're looking for and if its working or not

Comment: I don't know how much rows there would be for same object, it is not constant, i just show an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You original question clearly wanted the objects in the most recent groups, not all objects.  For this, you need to calculate both the max object id and the maximum generated time for other objects:

```
select *
from t cross join
     (select max(object_id) maxobject_id from t) maxt
where object_id = maxt.maxobject_id and
      generated_at > (select max(generated_at) from t where object_id <> maxt.maxobject_id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this, combining with `fthiella`'s answer about object_id(i'am looking not for a max but latest one) is what I am looking for!

Comment: +1 - Right on @Gordon Linoff - I was working out a similar solution when you posted. I went ahead and posted my answer anyways..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE object_id = (SELECT MAX(object_id) FROM table)`

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for - this would just select all rows with object_id = 4.

Comment: thanks for answer, but dugas right, I need only top group and the object_id is arbitrary

Comment: It worked before the question was edited.  I'd see if you can create a column that groups the chunks of measurements.  Picking out things based on the object_id of the latest entry won't work because you'll get later rows.  These can be filtered based on runs of "id" to get the last continuous chunk, but ids aren't always continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The below query would obtain the results:

```
select * from Measurements
left join Measurements as M2
on
(M2.generated_at > Measurements.generated_at and M2.object_id <> Measurements.object_id)
where 
M2.id IS NULL
and
Measurements.object_id = 
(select object_id from Measurements where generated_at = (select MAX(generated_at) from Measurements))
```